# Booleans in jquery plugins options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use some jquery plugins, some of them have options like:

```
$('#data-table').bootstrapTable({
    height: 250,
    clickToSelect: true,
    checkbox: true
});
```

The problem, in all plugins, is that they don't read the boolean options. In the upper code, the table loads with a 250px height, but  `clickToSelect` and `checkbox` are still `false`, the default value.

This happends in ALL plugins I use that has options, like the one in the example.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Because either the plugin is faulty or you are reading the documentation incorrectly. Booleans in object properties passed to a function work just fine.

Comment: Those are column options for bootstrapTable. Check my answer for an usage example of these properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read [documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) of each plugin. Different plugins offer different configuration options.

For bootstrap-table plugin, you need to define columns. 
**checkbox** and **clickToSelect** are options available for column configuration. This way you can use them:

```
 $('#table').bootstrapTable({
     columns: [{
         field: 'id',
         title: 'Item ID'
     }, {
         field: 'name',
         title: 'Item Name'
     }, {
         field: 'price',
         title: 'Item Price'
     }, {
         field: 'select',
         title: 'Select item',
         checkbox: true,
         clickToSelect: true
     }],
     data: [{
         id: 1,
         name: 'Item 1',
         price: '$1'
     }, {
         id: 2,
         name: 'Item 2',
         price: '$2'
     }]
 });
```